# css Menu dropdown is behind the slider

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I am in the process of creating a website, but the top menu is appearing below the slider and I am not sure where to change the z-index value. Hence giving you the site link. Apologize for that.
http://www.freshpotsolutions.com/testLab/selkar.com/test1/home1.html

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can add a z-index: 2 to the .box-section2 rule:

```
.box-section2 {
  ...
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not fixing it. the issue remains.